# How can I format AJAX data for a SelectList in WebForms?

Tags: javascript, ajax, webforms, selectlist

I am populating a SelectList w/ data that comes back from an AJAX call.  However, the data is showing up as one item w/ a really long name instead of several dozen items w/ short names.  I'm getting "ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO" instead of "ABC", "DEF", "GHI", etc.  So, my SelectList just gets one item attached w/ a long name.

If I view my returned data in a debugger, I can see the short values appearing on separate lines as desired.

I've tried using "html" instead of "json" for the return-type, but that had no effect.

Here is my server-side code:

```
private void GetItems(HttpContext context, int myID) 
{
    DataTable datatable = GetMyItems(myID);

    foreach (DataRow myRow in datatable.Rows)
    {
        Response.Write(myRow["ColumnName"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
    }
    Response.End();
}
```

And javascript...

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../myAjaxPage.aspx?myID=" + myID,
    type: 'POST',
    datatype: 'json',

    success: function (data) {
        $("<option>").attr("value", data).text(data).appendTo("#<%= mySelectList.ClientID %>");
    }
});
```

Comment: You're not really returning JSON or HTML from `GetItems`. `data` is just one long string, and with that one long string, you're only creating one <option> with that long string as its value. HTML rendering then turns the newlines into spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't returning JSON, you are just returning a string.  But, that's fine. Just split the string and iterate the resulting Array.

```
success: function (data) {
    $.each (data.split("\n"), function () {
        $("<option>").attr("value", this).text(this).appendTo("#<%= mySelectList.ClientID %>");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you return an object as an array instead of a string?  I think the newlines are being ignored in the ajax.  You can do an  `$.each(data)` if they're stored in an array object, which is what I think you're trying to do